# Matrix Operations in Google Script

Tags: matrix, google-apps-script

I'm trying to figure out if Google App Script language supports any sort of matrix operations that can be used on the back end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script is a variant of Javascript - so, yes, it can support matrix operations, or any other math you want to do. Also like Javascript, it cannot do so natively - you need to write the functions yourself, or find a library that suits.

For matrix operations in particular, here's an option. Jos de Jong's [**mathjs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjs) library for Node.js works as-is in Google Apps Script. You can read up on its support for matrices [here](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html).

- Copy the minimized `math.js` [raw source (v. 6.6.4)](https://unpkg.com/mathjs@6.6.4/dist/math.min.js), and paste it into a [new script file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/managing_projects#creatingFiles) in the script that you want to add the library to. With that done, the library is accessible as `math`, e.g. `math.someMethod()`
- Try the following example - the comments show what you can expect in the logs:

```js
    /**
     * Demonstrate mathjs array & matrix operations.
     */
    function matrix_demo() {
      var array = [[2, 0],[-1, 3]];               // Array
      var matrix = math.matrix([[7, 1],[-2, 3]]); // Matrix

      // perform a calculation on an array and matrix
      print( math.square(array) ); // Array,  [[4, 0], [1, 9]]
      print( math.square(matrix) ); // Matrix, [[49, 1], [4, 9]]

      // perform calculations with mixed array and matrix input
      print( math.add(array, matrix) ); // Matrix, [[9, 1], [-3, 6]]
      print( math.multiply(array, matrix) ); // Matrix, [[14, 2], [-13, 8]]

      // create a matrix. Type of output of function ones is determined by the
      // configuration option `matrix`
      print( math.ones(2, 3) ); // Matrix, [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
    }

    /**
     * Helper function to output a value in the console. Value will be formatted.
     * @param {*} value
     */
    function print (value) {
      var precision = 14;
      Logger.log(math.format(value, precision));
    }
```

Comment: For some reason, Apps Script timed out when pasting in the minified version, but the full version was able to be pasted in as a script: https://unpkg.com/mathjs@6.6.4/dist/math.js Note that one might also create a custom bundle which will contain only the functions you need: https://mathjs.org/docs/custom_bundling.html