# matrix operations in google script follow up

Tags: javascript, matrix, google-apps-script

I'd like to do some basic matrix operations in google app script.  I tried the solution to copy-n-paste math.js found in this thread:
[Matrix Operations in Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560969/matrix-operations-in-google-script)

But when I try to paste the code to the script file from inside my google spreadsheet, it always hangs.  I tried pasting portions at a time, but it always hangs when I reach the end.  I'm wondering if the file is too long for google script.  Fairly new to google app scripting, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is a possible reason that you have exceeded the maximum execution time in Google Apps Script. From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854573/exceeded-maximum-execution-time-in-google-apps-script), you could set up a time driven trigger to run the script every five minutes(or create a trigger programmatically using the [Script service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_script)).

Also, based from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703089/5832311), try to minimize the amount of calls to google services. For example, if you want to change a range of cells in the spreadsheets, don't read each one, mutate it and store it back. Instead read the whole range (using [`Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues%28%29)) into memory, mutate it and store all of it at once (using [`Range.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues%28Object%29)).

Additional reference: [Google Spreadsheet freezes when done running App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186489/google-spreadsheet-freezes-when-done-running-app-script)